# How can I select a drawing anchored in a header?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

If I add a drawing (or a text box) to a header and move it outside the header area (so that it is present in all the pages of the same style), I can no longer select it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else show me the way. In this case you have to **Shift+Click** the drawing object to be able to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Navigator to select the object: to open the navigator, hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or Menu `View` -> `Navigator` or select the compass icon from the side bar. All images are listed under `Images`, text frames under `Text Frames` and so on. Just click on the background image and double-click to select it:

[image]

Comment: Draw objects as in my sample are not listed (even thought there is a draw objects heading).

Comment: You're partly right :-) - they appear **only if you've set a name for them** (below `Draw objects` at the bottom). But using CTRL+click works in any case.